# Firebase Db ans eventlistener

Tags: json, swift, firebase

I am about to set a database and I will have to update it manually by uploading a json file.
But unfortunately, manual updates delate and replace data.

So I am wondering...
If I set an eventlistener on a key of the database, will it be triggered everytime I update the databse ?
Or, will it be smart enough to detect a difference from the previous update ?

**Example:**

From the update sequence below, if I set an eventlistener on "Key1", which one will trigger the listener ?

**Starting point:**
{
    "Key1":
            [
                {
                    "data1":"value1",
                    "data2":"value2"
                }
            ]
}

**1st Update:**
{
    "Key1":
            [
                {
                    "data1":"value1",
                    "data2":"value2"
                }
            ]
}

**2nd Update:**
{
    "Key1":
            [
                {
                    "data1":"value1",
                    "data2":"value2",
                    "data3":"value3"
                }
            ]
}

**3rd Update:**
{
    "Key1":
            [
                {
                    "data1":"value1",
                    "data3":"value3"
                }
            ]
}

Thanks

Comment: Please indicate when you cross-post: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/_YbtQN2f13E

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have different types of event listeners. So if you observe with `FIRDataEventType.value`, you will be notified on every change that happens in the node specified (or its descendants) - in your example, it would be the 2nd and 3rd updates.

But you can choose to be notified only when a child is added, or when it is removed, for example.

You can check [their documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Enums/FIRDataEventType) on the `FIRDataEventType` enum =D